# How can I replace first line of every file in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have 30 text files.

Then I have one text file with 30 lines. Let's call it `30lines.txt`

I want to replace the first line of each of the 30 text files with a corresponding line from `30lines.txt`

How do I do this?

Comment: Each file having its own corresponding line in `30lines.txt` ? You'll have to introduce logic then, and I don't think this will be possible with notepad++ alone. You'll have to write a program.

Comment: OK thanks. Is there any tool that allows me to quickly write simple scripts like these? I really don't want to write a c++ or a Java program for simple file handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy in **SynWrite** app. You have Python console: enter there N commands. E.g. commands to read contents of "30lines.txt" is:

```
from sw import *
file_open(r'c:\dir\30lines.txt')
text = ed.get_text_all()
text = text.split('\r\n')
print('Lines: '+str(len(text)))
```

to replace 1st line to "haha":

```
from sw import *
file_open(r'c:\new.txt')
ed.set_text_line(0, 'haha')
```